# WebApi Security - Customizing User model using Code First and EF

Tags: entity-framework, angularjs, security, asp.net-web-api, code-first

I have created a webapi 2 service that I need to secure. I am trying to use the Individual Accounts in VS2013 but I after much research I cannot figure out how to:

a. Customize the User model with my own properties (no such class exists in template)

b. Get access to User and Role contexts

I tried using the nuget's EFMembershipCodeFirst package but I noticed its deprecated, this package provided access to the required classes (User/Role).

There are plenty of examples for Mvc but I'm using Angularjs as the front end.

Does anyone know how I can customize the User model that vs2013 Individual Accounts template creates? Maybe I'm missing something obvious? I'm a bit of newbie when it comes to securing webAPIs. Thanks

Edit: UserManage.Create() only takes a password and a username, I need override it to also accept myUniqueId. Any thoughts?

[image]

Updated title for clarity + added image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Horizon_Net's suggestion, I created a custom class that derived from IdentityUser, but used the following as guidance:

[Here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/03/asp-net-identity-with-the-entity-framework.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The classes you should concentrate on are the **IdentityUser**, **UserManager** and **RoleManager** classes.

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes.aspx) example shows you how you can use them.

Because your using AngularJS an option would be to create an ASP.NET Web API backend.

The [official documentation](http://www.asp.net/identity) is a good starting point to become familiar with ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have created the Web API back-end, my issue is I need to secure it. I have read the documentation you provided, they are great for the basics but I need to know how to add my own data to the user profile (ie Unique table Id). Are there any books? I have read ASP. Web API Security and its quite abstract.

Comment: The only book I'm aware of is the one you mentioned. It is interesting, but, like you said, has some kind of abstraction. The first sample I provided shows how you can add your own data to a user profile (by deriving from **IdentityUser**). If we take the ID example, you don't have to extend the **IdentityUser** with f.e. a **ApplicationUser**, because **IdentityUser** already provides an ID property. Regarding your update: You have several choices. If the appropriate method is not overridable you could create an extension method, but keep in mind that this normally involves work against EF.